# Install Sitecore from EKS Cluster

Tags: solr, sitecore-api, aks, kubernetes, amazon-web-services

I followed [this](https://praveenmanchanablog.wordpress.com/2020/10/01/sitecore-on-aws-kubernetes-eks/) link, to install Sitecore 10.3.

But in real time, we need to update the `secret` in `aws secret manager`. So, I followed [this](https://waswani.medium.com/integrating-secrets-manager-with-aws-eks-79c93e70c74e) link, All the pods are working as expected.

But When I tried to run job ex- solr-init, I could not see the indexes created in the server, `kubectl port-forward solr-546564f77b-5d28x -n sitecore 8983:8983`

If We used to create secret through our local Customization process, it's working absolutely fine but not AWS secret manager.

Can you please help me to find out the solution?

Thanks